# Setting content of [app].exe.config file in .NET Core Web application

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am building a .NET Core web application (using net461 framework) that uses the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework package. The package requires some settings in the [app].exe.config file in order to work.

Specifically it needs the following sections to be registered

```
<entityFramework>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
          type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
        <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver"
            type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
        <edmMappings>
            <edmNumberMapping>
                <add NETType="int16" MinPrecision="1" MaxPrecision="4" DBType="Number"/>
                <add NETType="int32" MinPrecision="5" MaxPrecision="9" DBType="Number"/>
                <add NETType="int64" MinPrecision="10" MaxPrecision="19" DBType="Number"/>
            </edmNumberMapping>
        </edmMappings>
    </version>
</oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

**My question is:** How do I set these settings in a .NET Core application?
The settings are not carried over from the web.config file.

In an ordinary .NET application they will be carried over from the app.settings file.

Thanks!

Regards,
Jesper

Comment: By a wild guess I found out that you can just add an App.config file to your .NET Core web project, and the build pipeline will then add these settings to your [app].exe.config file in your build output.